# TFS 2010 - Nightly Builds of WiX MSI for WebApplication/Windows Service and install to web server

Tags: powershell, tfs, wix, tfsbuild

Can you please enlighten me on my task?

My task is to create a nightly builds of MSI (done in WiX) and install it to our web server using powershell.

1. TFSBuild server build an MSI
2. Run Powershell to uninstall and install the newly build MSI.
3. Run Powershell to Start the windows service.

The WiX MSI contains WindowsService and a Web Application.

Below are list of what i have done so far:

1. Solution.sln :  Configuration Manager and "x86|debug" (check all the files that needs to be built '.wixproj' already checked)
2. Created a build definition and set "x86|debug" for configurations to build and set projects to build is my solution file.

but after the build has completed, there is no MSI files on the binaries build folder on the build server. :(

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few pointers:

- Have you installed Wix on the buildserver?
- Which version of Team Build are you using? 2010 has the preference here as the tooling has progressed a lot since 2008.
- Did you configure to run msbuild in auto or x86 mode (auto can result in 64-bit which has some issues with the latest stable version of wix) [link](http://www.havecomputerwillcode.com/blog/?p=421) [link](http://www.havecomputerwillcode.com/blog/?p=421)
- Is your build agent running on a 64 bit server? If so, you either need to run the build agent under an administrative account or do some mucking around in the registry to fix issues with Wix. [link](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/11/14/wix-projects-vs-tfs-2010-team-build.aspx)

To install the build using Powershell, I personally prefer [TFSDeployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/), which can monitor your build output and trigger powershell scripts based on the build outcome. It takes away the deployment responsibility from the build server and saves a lot of headaches around security and account configurations.

Comment: I agree. I'd use a mechanism that subscribes to build completion events and then processes a workflow ( such as deployment to a server )  after the build is done.

Comment: this answer saves my time and effort. thanks a lot jessehouwing!